# Comando no SQL já com calculo correto

Tags: sql

Nós temos um diferencial no pagamento do ICMS e eu gostaria de ao exportar uma planilha o qual já criei o comando, criasse também qual o valor que vamos pagar do ICMS.

No caso seria o seguinte.:

> Onde destacamos 10% de ICMS, nós pagamos somente 4% efetivamente.
>   Onde destacamos 4% do ICMS, pagamos efetivamente 1,4%

O Comando Atual:

```
SELECT DISTINCT nf.codloja, 
                nf.dtemissao, 
                nf.numnota, 
                ni.icms, 
                Sum(ni.subtoticms) AS toticms 
FROM   notafiscal nf 
       JOIN nfitens ni 
         ON ni.codnf = nf.codnf 
WHERE  dtemissao BETWEEN '06/01/2019' AND '06/30/2019' 
       AND COALESCE(nf.anulada, 0) = 0 
       AND COALESCE(nf.cancelada, 0) = 0 
       AND codloja = 2 
       AND COALESCE(nf.protocolonfe, '') <> '' 
GROUP  BY 1, 
          2, 
          3, 
          4
```

Comment: Quais valores exatamente você quer exibir?

Comment: As observações: "Onde destacamos 10% de ICMS, nós pagamos somente 4% efetivamente." e "Onde destacamos 4% do ICMS, pagamos efetivamente 1,4%" se referem a que campos de sua(s) tabela(s)?

Comment: Ronaldo,Gostaria de já fazer o calculo do valor real que irei pagar em cada uma das situações. Com base no valor do ICMS que já possuo e sabendo qual foi o percentual pago na Nota.

Comment: Na coluna `icms` da tabela `nfitens` teriam as porcentagens de ICMS (10% e 4%)? E na coluna `subtoticms` teria o valor pago? Coloque alguns registros de exemplo de cada tabela, para  ajudar a entender melhor.

Comment: Ele retorna com o seguinte exemplo. 
COD LOJA - DT EMISSAO - NUM NOTA - ICMS - SOMA DO ICMS 
1 - 25/06/2019- 25656 - 4%  - 237,00
1 - 25/06/2019 - 25656 - 10% - 421,00

Answer (score -1):

Supondo que em suas tabelas você não tenha o valor da nota para recálculo do ICMS, e portanto você precisa recalcular a partir do valor de ICMS de que dispõe, e que a coluna icms contenha uma string com o percentual, tente:

```
SELECT DISTINCT nf.codloja, 
                nf.dtemissao, 
                nf.numnota, 
                ni.icms, 
                Sum(CASE WHEN ni.icms = '4%' THEN (ni.subtoticms * 0.014) / 0.04
                         WHEN ni.icms = '10%' THEN (ni.subtoticms * 0.04) / 0.1
                         ELSE ni.subtoticms
                    END) AS toticms 
FROM   notafiscal nf 
       JOIN nfitens ni 
         ON ni.codnf = nf.codnf 
WHERE  dtemissao BETWEEN '06/01/2019' AND '06/30/2019' 
       AND nf.anulada IS NOT NULL 
       AND nf.cancelada IS NOT NULL 
       AND codloja = 2 
       AND nf.protocolonfe <> '' 
GROUP  BY 1, 
          2, 
          3, 
          4
```

Se não for isto explique como estão organizados seus dados.

Comment: No comando que eu coloquei, os dados retornam com o valor do ICMS já pegando da Nota e também a alíquota.

Pensei algo parecido com o que tenho em outro comando que fiz o recalculo pra PIS e COFINS:
<code>

cast( cast(nf.total as numeric(10,2)) * 0.0165 as numeric(10,2))as valorpisnovo, cast( cast(nf.total as numeric(10,2)) * 0.076 as numeric(10,2)) as valorcofinsnovo, nf.valoricms from notafiscal nf

Comment: De acordo com o que você disse não basta então apenas identificar e trocar o percentual de 4% para 1.4% e de 10% para 4% ? Não entendi o significado destes multiplicadores 0.0165 (16.5%) e 0.076 (7.6%).